# Python function for xml list

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have parsed XML file looking like this. Maybe I just didn't copy well,but it's ok, so, here it is:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE raml SYSTEM 'raml20.dtd'>
        <raml version="2.0" xmlns="raml20.xsd">
        <cmData type="actual">
            <managedObject class="LN" distName="PTR" id="2425">
              <p name="aak">220</p>
              <p name="orp">05</p>
              <p name="name">Portro</p>
              <p name="optres">false</p>
              <p name="optblu">false</p>
              <p name="aoptdet">false</p>
              <p name="advcell">false</p>
              <list name="sibList">
                <item>
                  <p name="sibcity">177</p>
                  <p name="sibrep">2</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <p name="sibcity">177</p>
                  <p name="sibrep">1</p>
                </item>
              </list>
            </managedObject>
            <managedObject class="LN" distName="KRNS" id="93886">
              <p name="aak">150</p>
              <p name="orp">05</p>
              <p name="name">Portro</p>
              <p name="optres">false</p>
              <p name="optblu">tru</p>
              <p name="aoptdet">false</p>
              <p name="advcell">true</p>
              <list name="sibList">
                <item>
                  <p name="sibcity">177</p>
                  <p name="sibrep">1</p>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <p name="sibcity">180</p>
                  <p name="sibrep">2</p>
                </item>
               </list>
            </managedObject>
             ....
            <managedObject>
             ...
            </managedObject>

            ...
        </cmData>
        </raml>
```

I need to go through all "managedObject" and compare every parameter(p name) from first managedObject with parameters (aak, orp, etc.) from another managedObjects, and get output of different parameters and values of them, if there is no different values of parameters, do nothing. I wrote code for comparasion, but I don't know how to go through list (it's named "sibList") and compare parameters. I wrote this function, where key is "p name" and value is value of "p name":

```
temp = []
for i in temp_ln:
    for j, k in zip(i.getchildren(), i):
        temp.append([i.get('distName'), j.get('name'), j.text])

    tempdict = {}
    for i in temp_ln:
        td = {}
        for j in i.getchildren():
            td.update({j.get('name'): j.text})
        tempdict.update({i.get('distName'): td})


elements_list = {}
   if j.get('name') == 'sibList':
            for item in j.getchildren():
                for w in item.getchildren():
                    elements_list.update({ w.get('name'): w.text})

        main_dif = {}
        for key, value in tempdict.iteritems():
            dif_k = {}
            for k, v in value.iteritems():
                try: 
                    a = ref[k]
                except:
                    a = None
                if v != a:
                    if k == 'name':
                        pass
                    else:
                        dif_k.update({k:(v, a)})
            main_dif.update({key:dif_k})
```

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. Umm, basically you want to traverse the XML and work on all `managedObject` nodes? Have you tried `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup`?

Comment: Yes, I tried. 
I have updated my code.
But now I can't declare sibList to specific managedObject. 
At the end, I need excel file with managedObjects as a columns, and parameters as a rows. Values will be text, for example : 220, 05, Portro, etc.

Comment: And I need to mention, I used etree parser. @techouse

Comment: the indentation for that block of code is very wonky, please paste the code into SO, highlight it then use the `{}` button to format the code block.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I'm new here.
I don't even think that my code is much important, I just wanna ask if there is any python function to catch that "p name" parameters from lists and marge it with others @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen

Comment: Your description for what you want to do is quite vague but I'm going say there probably isn't an existing function that will do exactly what you want to do, you will probably need to write it yourself.

Comment: I know that, that's why I started to write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that parse the XML file, and compares each managedObject with all others, and print out the resulting diff object.

```
import json
from xml.etree import ElementTree


tree = ElementTree.parse('raml20.xml')

ns = {'ns': 'raml20.xsd'}
nsP, nsList, nsItem = ('{%s}%s' % (ns['ns'], i) for i in ('p', 'list', 'item'))


def pkv(o):
    """Return dict with name:text of p elements"""
    return {k.attrib['name']: k.text for k in o.iter(nsP)}


def parse(tree):
    root = tree.getroot()
    objs = {}
    for mo in root.findall('./ns:cmData/ns:managedObject', ns):
        obj = pkv(mo)
        for i in mo.iter(nsList):
            obj[i.attrib['name']] = [pkv(j) for j in i.iter(nsItem)]
        objs[mo.attrib['distName']] = obj
    return objs


def diff_dicts(d1, d2, ignore_keys=set()):
    """Return dict with differences between the dicts provided as arguments"""
    k1 = set(d1.keys())
    k2 = set(d2.keys())
    diff = {}
    diff.update(
        {i: (d1[i], d2[i]) for i in (k1 & k2) - ignore_keys if d1[i] != d2[i]})
    diff.update({i: (d1.get(i), d2.get(i)) for i in (k1 ^ k2) - ignore_keys})
    return diff


def diff_lists(l1, l2):
    """Return dict with differences between lists of dicts provided as arguments"""
    diff = {}
    # note: assumes that lists are of same length
    for i, (d1, d2) in enumerate(zip(l1, l2)):
        d = diff_dicts(d1, d2)
        if d:
            diff[i] = d
    return diff


def diff_objects(o1, o2):
    """Return dict with differences between two objects (dicts) provided as arguments"""
    listkeys = set(
        i for o in (o1, o2) for i in o if isinstance(o.get(i), list))
    diff = diff_dicts(o1, o2, listkeys)
    for i in listkeys:
        if i in o1 and i in o2:
            diff.update({i: diff_lists(o1[i], o2[i])})
        else:
            diff.update({i: (o1.get(i), o2.get(i))})
    return diff


def compare_objects(objs):
    diffs = []
    keys = list(objs)
    for k1, k2 in zip(keys[:-1], keys[1:]):
        o1, o2 = objs[k1], objs[k2]
        diff = diff_objects(o1, o2)
        if diff:
            diffs.append((k1, k2, diff))
    return diffs


res = compare_objects(parse(tree))
print(json.dumps(res, indent=2))
```

I've tested with the following `raml20.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE raml SYSTEM 'raml20.dtd'>
<raml version="2.0" xmlns="raml20.xsd">
  <cmData type="actual">
    <managedObject class="LN" distName="PTR" id="2425">
      <p name="aak">220</p>
      <p name="orp">05</p>
      <p name="name">Portro</p>
      <p name="optres">false</p>
      <p name="optblu">false</p>
      <p name="aoptdet">false</p>
      <p name="advcell">false</p>
      <list name="sibList">
        <item>
          <p name="sibcity">177</p>
          <p name="sibrep">2</p>
        </item>
        <item>
          <p name="sibcity">177</p>
          <p name="sibrep">1</p>
        </item>
      </list>
    </managedObject>
    <managedObject class="LN" distName="KRNS" id="93886">
      <p name="aak">150</p>
      <p name="orp">05</p>
      <p name="name">Portro</p>
      <p name="optres">false</p>
      <p name="optblu">tru</p>
      <p name="aoptdet">false</p>
      <p name="advcell">true</p>
      <list name="sibList">
        <item>
          <p name="sibcity">177</p>
          <p name="sibrep">1</p>
        </item>
        <item>
          <p name="sibcity">180</p>
          <p name="sibrep">2</p>
        </item>
       </list>
    </managedObject>
  </cmData>
</raml>
```

The resulting diff object is:

```
[
  [
    "PTR",
    "KRNS",
    {
      "advcell": [
        "false",
        "true"
      ],
      "optblu": [
        "false",
        "tru"
      ],
      "sibcity": [
        "177",
        "180"
      ],
      "aak": [
        "220",
        "150"
      ],
      "sibrep": [
        "1",
        "2"
      ],
      "sibList": {
        "0": {
          "sibrep": [
            "2",
            "1"
          ]
        },
        "1": {
          "sibcity": [
            "177",
            "180"
          ],
          "sibrep": [
            "1",
            "2"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: @jovicbg You're welcome. If the answer solves your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: This is great. 
Now I need compare all managedObjects with just one, refferent one.

Comment: If you have a reference managedObject, just modify the `compare_objects` function to compare with that specific object. See this gist for example: https://gist.github.com/jcbsv/1a7f37e93e9f3d25470f27e15c365817